# How to call a method from one activity which is defined in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my Activity class

```
public class A extends Activity
{
.......
.......
//here i have to call my test() method of B activity
new B.test();
}
```

This is my next Activity

```
public class B extends Activity
{
......
public void test(){
//some code  }
}
```

But the test() method is not not executing. I put a Toast message in test() method. but it is not showing the Toast message. How to call that test() method. Where am I wrong? Do i have to override onCreate() in B activity? Please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write test method in separate class which doesn't extends Activity.So that you can call the method from two activities whenever you need.

An activity is a different screen and you can call it by intent,so that it can be shown on screen

Comment: +1 its great idea .if that method involves display things just pass context of calling activity like c.test(A.this); so in that test method we can use the context of Activity B Class.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
public class A extends Activity{ 
     B.test(); 
    }
```

and

```
  public class B extends Activity{   
       public static void test(){
       System.out.println("test method of B is called.");  
}   
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. If you want a static helper method that is used in A and B write it in a separate Class and call this class from both Activities.

Comment: I Agreed to Janusz. It is better you create a separate class containing satics methods like this which returns your answer. Insted of putting that code in class which extends Activity. You can tell your requirement in detail then we could provide better solution.